# How to detect whether a URL is local area network(LAN) url by PHP?

Tags: php, ip

I have a url such as `https://10.1.1.1/test/index.php`, it's a LAN url, I want to just add url which is not LAN url, so I want to make a detect function which can return `false` for above url. What I wrote is:

```
function is_local($url){
    if(stristr($url,'localhost') || stristr($url,'127.') || stristr($url,'192.') ){
        return true;    
    }else{
        return false;   
    }   
}
```

It's not very satisfactory, because `var_dump(is_local('http://1.127.1.1/index.php'));` returns `true`, etc.

Is there a better and perfect way to do this check in PHP?

Comment: Just to put my two cents in, you could use a regex like `https?:\/\/(localhost|127\.|192\.)[^\/]*\/.*?`, see an example here: https://regex101.com/r/xY4kH8/1

Comment: In addition to this being a dupe, your use of stristr is also going to always evaluate to true if "127." or "192." exists anywhere in the string. Use strpos instead and check if that equals to `0`, ie. `strpos($url, '127.') === 0`

Comment: @sebastianForsberg: And what about the `http/https://` part? 127 won`t be in the first position.

Comment: Is there a better way rather than regex or format determination, because there's also some situation LAN begins with 10.*